# Rails 3 + Omniauth. When a user clicks "Don't Allow" for FB, how can I customize the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Right now if a user clicks "Don't Allow" the popup window goes back to the site with the error message: "Could not authorize you from Facebook because "The user denied your request."

Any ideas on how I can handle this failure in my auth controller so I can close the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to redirect the user if the authentication fail so add this to your routes :

```
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
```

you can look at my example app here : https://github.com/senayar/facebook_connect